# Como calcular o produto da multiplicação dos elementos de um array de números?

Tags: java

Como percorrer um array de números e calcular o resultado da multiplicação de todos os seus elementos?

Por exemplo, com [1, 4, 7] obter  28, que é 1 * 4 * 7.

Answer (score 1):

Bem vindo ao SoPT!

Bom, levando em consideração o nível da questão que apresentou acredito que deva estar aprendendo o laço `for` correto? Vou deixar aqui uma solução que acredito que esteja mais de acordo com sua linha de estudos, mas há soluções melhores para essa situação :)

```
int arrayNumeros[] = {1,4,7};
int total = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < arrayNumeros.length; i++) 
{
   total = arrayNumeros[i] * total;
}
System.out.println(total);
```

Note que inseri tanto a variável total como o array do tipo INT devido a no seu exemplo você utilizar apenas números inteiros, caso queira trabalhar com números decimais deve alterar os dois para o tipo FLOAT.